How to create a rank using multiple columns with DAX? Power BI
I want to create a rank grouping by month and category using dax. Basically, like that:

I've tried the following code, but it returns the row sale and not the rank:
TOP 10 =
CALCULATE([Total Sales],
    topn(10, ALLSELECTED(category),[Total Sales]),
    values(category)
)

Can someone explain how to create that rank and why this code was returning the sales value of each line and not the rank?

If you want to rank them, why not use RANKX() on the outside and SUMMARIZE() to group by month and category?

I'm kinda new to PBI, can you give me a example of how to do it? I can't understand it from Google....
